# How to remove or update Excel document Properties and Personal information using java?

Tags: java

[Excel Document Properties Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ8oh.png)

Please see the attached image, I'm wanted to remove highlighted properties from the document.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far please

Comment: @ekstreom actually I'm converting xls file to xlsx file using apache poi library but I ' m getting Exception  --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298310/org-apache-poi-hssf-record-recordformatexception-expected-size-18-but-got-0 . When I have tried to convert same file after removing highlighted properties in image then it's successfully converted.